# Logic App Conditions - how to fix my conditions?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I recently started working with logic apps.
I got stuck with a simple array filter.

How do I get to fix the following?:

`@and(equals(item()?['ReportName']?['Value'], body('Get_response_details')?['rb6faae7228c4454d91422175db06cfde']), and(equals(item()?['Environment']?['Value'],body('Get_response_details')?['r35825e12ace649ec964d24a86d851762']), or(equals(item()?['Role']?['Value'],body('Get_response_details')?['rc456e0fddc9440a09a67cbf979173354'])), equals(item()?['Role']?['Value'], 'AppViewer')))`

I want to have a filter that filters when Report name = rb6faae7228c4454d91422175db06cfde,
when Environment = r35825e12ace649ec964d24a86d851762,
AND when Role equals both rc456e0fddc9440a09a67cbf979173354 or 'Appviewer'
( this should return both roles )

That last one I'm struggling with.

Cheers,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets seem to be in the wrong place. Can you try this?

```
@and(equals(item()?['ReportName']?['Value'], body('Get_response_details')?['rb6faae7228c4454d91422175db06cfde']), and(equals(item()?['Environment']?['Value'],body('Get_response_details')?['r35825e12ace649ec964d24a86d851762']), or(equals(item()?['Role']?['Value'],body('Get_response_details')?['rc456e0fddc9440a09a67cbf979173354']), equals(item()?['Role']?['Value'], 'AppViewer'))))
```

Comment: Great! thank you! 
I already tried that, but seems like the "Appviewer" had more capitals 'APPViewer"
Thanks !